# Why does google-chrome-devtools identifies less number of elements through XPath then number of elements identified through CssSelector

Tags: css, google-chrome, xpath, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to identify the elements containing the *reviews* on this [webpage](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4209788/reviews) using [[image]google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools).

Using the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//div[@class='text show-more__control']
```

The number of elements identified are: **15**

Snapshot:

[image: xpath_15]

Using the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

```
div.text.show-more__control
```

The number of elements identified are: **25**

Snapshot:

[image: cssSelectors_25]

So, why does *google-chrome-devtools* identifies less number of elements through *XPath* then number of elements identified through *CssSelector*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath is checking `@class` attribute values lexically for the string, `text show-more__control`.

The CSS expression is checking semantically for `@class` attribute values that indicate that the `div` should have both the `text` and the `show-more__control` styles.

There are 10 `div` elements that satisfy the CSS semantic selection criteria that fail the XPath lexical criteria because their `@class` lexically is

```
text show-more__control clickable
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The usual workaround for testing `@class` is to pad and check each class separately:

```
//div[    contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' text ')
      and contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' show-more__control ') ]
```

This XPath returns 25 `div` elements, just like the CSS selector.

**Note:**  Particularly tricky here is that `clickable` parts of the `div/@class` attribute value are not present in the static source, only in the dynamic properties on the `div` objects.

Comment: One question is there any fundamental difference between `//div[    contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' text ') and contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' show-more__control ') ]` (using _concat_ andspace induced) and `//div[contains(@class, 'text') and contains(@class, 'show-more__control')]` (without space and concat())? Both seems to be returning **25**

Comment: Yes, without the delimiting spacing, there can be false matches of `'text'` against classes such as `'texting'` or `'context'`.