# Difference between contains and equals in XPath - selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

Hey All I gave a question regarding xpath locator in selenium.
I have a test that if I use the next code:

```
locator = By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion']");`
```

everything is working since I user "class="

However if I change it and use contains :

```
locator = By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion')]");
```

I get

```
ERROR: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion')]"}
```

I do not understand what is the difference, and why If I use contains it not find.

Comment: It should work, I'm guessing it's timing issue rather than xpath issue. Try waiting for few seconds to check.

Comment: This xpath in second case should have captured the first one.

Comment: Have you checked how many matching elements with contains xpath. If it is only one, it should work as expected. Else, if you have more than one matching elements, change the xpath or pass index to identify your expected element in it.

Comment: Yes only one elements, I think it is time issue, since it sometimes work and sometimesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

The *xpath* as:

```
//div[@class='ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion']
```

is checking `@class` attribute values lexically for the string:

```
ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion
```

Where as *xpath* as:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion')]
```

is checking the substring **`ant-notification-notice ant-notification-notice-closable ng-trigger ng-trigger-notificationMotion`** within the `@class` attribute value.

I feel it would be a better idea to restrict the `@class` *attributes* as follows:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice') and contains(@class, 'ant-notification-notice-closable')][contains(@class, 'ng-trigger') and contains(@class, 'ng-trigger-notificationMotion')]
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Why does google-chrome-devtools identifies less number of elements through XPath then number of elements identified through CssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535678/why-does-google-chrome-devtools-identifies-less-number-of-elements-through-xpath)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and/or is not correct. If you are looking for @class='x' and it finds it, using contains(@class, 'x') will work also. Breaking each class out into separate strings doesn't explain or fix the issue either. It's likely a timing issue.